# JetBrains CLion gives "undefined reference to" error when running project but command line compiles just fine

Tags: c++, g++, clion, jetbrains-ide

Running Ubuntu OS, latest LTS version. When I run the project it gives me many "undefined reference to (function from SDL library)", but when I compile in the command line using

`g++ main.cpp -lSDL -lSDL_ttf`

It compiles just fine to a .out file and can be run.

I tried many people methods shared by other people on StackOverflow but none of them worked.

Here's my CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Epic)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(Epic main.cpp)
```

and my includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
```

What should I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your CMakeLists.txt does not indicate to link any libraries. Merely including the SDL header files tells the compiler that you intend to use these functions; it does not say where to find them. You need to add a TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Epic SDL SDL_tff) statement in CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your reply. It still fails, and as soon as I refresh the cmakelists.txt it gives me this error: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "Epic" which is not built by this
  project. How would I go about fixing this as well?

Comment: @YesPleaseAllah Where did you add the statement? You should add it after the ADD_EXECUTABLE statement.

Comment: it gave me a different error this time. 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL_tff

Seems like it doesn't want me to compile it within clion at all, haha.

Comment: You can add LINK_DIRECTORIES(<library directory>) before the TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES statement, where <library directory> is the directory where your SDL and SDL_ttf libraries are. Also the second library should be SDL_ttf, I think.